# Removing a substring from a string in python

Tags: python, regex

```
import string

def remove_all(substr, str):
    index = 0
    length = len(substr)
    while string.find(str, substr) != -1:
        index = string.find(str, substr)
        str = str[0:index] + str[index+length:]
    return str

s = "ABC_Y6N02.20.0025D_BF3DAC.tgz.bin"

print(s)

s = remove_all(r'_bf3dac',s.lower())

print(s)
```

The output of this program is

```
ABC_Y6N02.20.0025D_BF3DAC.tgz.bin
abc_y6n02.20.0025d.tgz.bin
```

I want to drop the `d` from `0025d` as well. Or basically I want to drop the last letter from before `.tgz.bin` how do I do this?

Basically I want the output to be 
      `abc_y6n02.20.0025.tgz.bin`
instead of 
      `abc_y6n02.20.0025d.tgz.bin`

Comment: What, precisely, is your question?

Comment: @Robᵩ - Please see updated question

Comment: Are opposed to `import re` and using regular expreessions?

Comment: Not overly clear what you want to happen here.  Are you just trying to remove the character before the specified sub-string?  Are you trying to remove all trailing letters before the removed sub-string?  Or are you trying to meet some other type of specification?

Comment: Aside:, you might replace your existing function with `return str.replace(substr, '')`.

Comment: Why didn't use `index-1` like this?  `str = str[0:index-1] + str[index+length:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: to drop the end of the string starting from the character before the underscore, but preserving the extension you can use a regex:

```
import re
s = "ABC_Y6N02.20.0025D_BF3DAC.tgz.bin"
print( re.sub(r"^(.*)[^_]_[^\.]*(\.tgz\.bin)$", r"\1\2",s ).lower())
```

returns

```
abc_y6n02.20.0025.tgz.bin
```

Comment: So you want to drop the end of the string starting from the character before the underscore, but preserving the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Regex can solve this fairly easily

```
import re

s = "ABC_Y6N02.20.0025D_BF3DAC.tgz.bin"
re.sub(r"\w_bf3dac", "", s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Will ouput
`'ABC_Y6N02.20.0025.tgz.bin'`

Comment: I think he wants to lose the d also... `re.sub(r'._bf3dac','','ABC_Y6N02.20.0025D_BF3DAC.tgz.bin', flags=re.IGNORECASE)`